# TFS 2017 build of ordered CodedUI unit tests doesn't give detailed results - Consider all tests as one test

Tags: unit-testing, tfsbuild, coded-ui-tests, ordered-test

I'm using tfs 2017 to run CodedUI ordered unit tests. These are my build steps:
[image]
These are my "Run Functional Tests" configurations:
[image]
And these are the "Publish Test Results" (I'm not sure they are correct):
[image]

The TestAgent is deployed and the tests are running fine, The problem is that the test results appear as only one result and I can't see detailed result for each test. This is how my tests results looks like (The attachments are screen shots I take for each test):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your situation and TFS will treat the tests as one in the log:

```
DistributedTests: Total Tests : 1, Passed Tests : 0
```

It's a know issue, please refer below link:

> [**How to display test results of individual test in the ordered test
>   suite in TFS Web**](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/2803)
>
> This is a **limitation** of the **run functional test task**. You can
>   publish the .trx file using the "publish test results" task and it
>   will show you all the tests but you wont know which ".orderedtest"
>   they were associated with etc.

You need either open  `*.trx` file  in Visual Studio or use Publish Test Results task(need to check continue on error).

[image]

Besides also change the outcome from failed to all in the test result page.

Comment: I unchecked but got the same results

Comment: I tried to publish the .trx file on the Publish Test Results task (see in my question). But I guess I give the wrong path or expression in "Test Results Files" because it doesn't find anything.

Comment: @AmirMonovich Could you find the `.trx` file in the build agent  corresponding folder? If  not , there maybe something wrong with the path. (Maybe lacking of permission )